# No implicit Ordering defined for scala.slick.lifted.ColumnOrdered[Long]

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I'm using slick 2.0 via play plugin and the following is my table mapping

```
class Tasks(tag: Tag) extends Table[Task](tag, "Tasks"){
    def id   = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def txt  = column[String]("txt")
    def done = column[Boolean]("done")
    def * = (id, txt, done) <> (Task.tupled, Task.unapply)
}
```

Then, I created TableQuery object like this

`val tasks = TableQuery[Tasks]`

I used `tasks.list` to get `List[Task]` which returns correctly
but when I want to sort the result by using `tasks.list.sortBy(_.id.get.desc)`
I got this error instead

> No implicit Ordering defined for scala.slick.lifted.ColumnOrdered[Long].

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to sort first and then call `.list()`:

```
tasks.sortBy(_.id.desc).list()
```

When calling `list()` you are executing the invoker and that's too late to add the sorting on the sql level, of course you can always sort the collection you get back using the list `sortBy` method.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. BTW, I got another error
`Caught exception while computing default value for Rep[Option[_]].getOrElse -- This cannot be done lazily when the value is needed on the database side`

Comment: It seems like .get causes the problem. I removed it and it works.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes the `.get` shouldn't be used, Slick is able to order even if the field is an `Option`.